# Notation confusion for "closed linear span" and "intersection of orthogonal projections"

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, lattice-orders

This is merely about notations. In Conway's *Functional Analysis* textbook, exercise I.2.4 on p.11 to be precise, the *closed linear span* of a set $A\subset H$, where $H$ is a hilbert space, is defined as the intersection of all closed subspaces containing set $A$, and is denoted as $\vee A$.

However, in the subject of von Neumann algebras, there is the topic of *lattice of projections*. There, for two orthogonal projections $p,q$, along with their ranges $Y,Z\subset H$, which are closed subspaces, the *greatest lower bound* of $p$ and $q$ is denoted as $p\wedge q$, which is defined to be the orthogonal projection onto the intersection $Y\cap Z$. Here it is also customary to write the intersection as $Y \wedge Z$. This is consistent with the general definition of *greatest lower bound* in order theory.

So my question is, why using different symbols, $\vee$ and $\wedge$, in these two situations, when they both mean intersections of some closed subspaces, respectively? Is it just Conway's weird notation, or is there actually something deeper about this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of all closed subspaces containing $A$ is equal to the smallest closed subspace that contains $A$, hence some kind of infimum, which justifies the notation $\vee A$.

Comment: Using that notation, we can write $$\vee A:=\bigwedge_{A\subset M\text{, where }M\subset H\text{ is closed}} M.$$ Just looks a little weird

Comment: But is is similar to the definition of the infimum: it is the largest lower bound, i.e., the supremum of the lower bounds. Also $\liminf$ is a construction involving sup's of inf's. Seems to be  a common theme :)